# ReadingChanged never called for Accelerometer on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I'm trying to use the C++ Accelerometer interface in the Windows::Devices::Sensors namespace on the Windows Phone 8.  The code is very similar to a C# project I have that works, but I can't get the C++ event to fire like I can with my C# code.

My C++ code is a C# project with a C++ component, the C++ component just opens up the Accelerometer device for reading, and then tries to setup an event to fire whenever data is ready:

```
AccelerometerWrapper::AccelerometerWrapper() {
    Accelerometer^ acc = Accelerometer::GetDefault();
    accReading = acc->ReadingChanged::add( ref new TypedEventHandler<Accelerometer^, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs^>(this, &AccelerometerWrapper::ReadingChanged));
}

void AccelerometerWrapper::ReadingChanged(Accelerometer^ sender, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs^ e) {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, my `ReadingChanged()` function is never being called.  I've looked around for a `Start()` method or somesuch but I can't find anything.  I'm basing most of my knowledge off of the [AccelerometerCPP example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Accelerometer-Sensor-Sample-22982671), but I can't actually test that as it is a generic WinRT (e.g. Windows 8, not Windows Phone 8) example, and my computer does not have an accelerometer.  Everything compiles and runs, the event is just never triggered.

EDIT: I have successfully run a test to verify that I can manually call `acc->GetCurrentReading()`, so the accelerometer is working, it just seems to be the event that is not getting triggered.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a C++ expert, but the new Accelerometer sensor works on my machine using C#.

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var accelerometer = Accelerometer.GetDefault();
    if (accelerometer != null)
    {
        accelerometer.ReadingChanged += accelerometer_ReadingChanged;
    }
}

void accelerometer_ReadingChanged(Accelerometer sender, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(args.Reading.AccelerationX + ", " + args.Reading.AccelerationY + "," + args.Reading.AccelerationZ);
}
```

When we run that code snippet we can see the following expected output:
 [image: Output]

Just a guess for C++, do you need to cache the Accelerometer instance somewhere instead of letting it go out of scope?